# How do you pass data between views using a UINavigationController

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have tried using the obvious method as outlined in the following example but my passed variable (*rootcategory*) is still **nil** on viewDidLoad in the loaded view.

This is my code:

```
CategoryViewController *viewController = [[CategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.categoryViewController.rootCategory = @"433";
self.categoryViewController = viewController;
[viewController release];
```

I am synthesizing a property in the header as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *rootCategory;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating viewController, and try to change self.categoryViewController before it is assigned to viewController.

```
CategoryViewController *viewController = [[CategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
viewController.rootCategory = @"433";
self.categoryViewController = viewController;
[viewController release];
```

should work.

Comment: hasn't helped Im afraid made no difference

Comment: would you mind telling me the difference between using self and not, Im guessing its not like this. in c# (my background)

Comment: What are @property of rootCategory and categoryViewController?
rootCategory should be "copy" or "retain" and categoryViewController should be "retain".

Using self means use the defined setter (via @property, in this case)

Comment: change your property to:
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString *rootCategory;
and make sure your categoryViewController has "retain" property.

Comment: sorry Stephen your amends were correct the key part was assigning to the viewController and not self.viewController. Not sure how my test failed before

Answer (score 0):

What does your header file for CategoryViewController look like?  Did you define rootCategory as a property?  Is it synthesized or did you write your own setter and getter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `viewDidLoad` is called on the new instance before `initWithNibName:` returns, so you'd be setting your properties after it's called.

Comment: So which method could I put my execution code in to pick up the variable in?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but `viewDidLoad` is called before you set the properties (like iKenndac pointed out).

You should use the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method instead. As the method name suggests, this is called right before the view appears on screen.